# Запятая перед "вследствие"

Tags: запятые, предлоги

**В той, которую мы обсудили выше, был выдан дополнительный мут, который был верным, но оказался неверным(,) вследствие обстоятельств, за которые никто ответственность на данный момент не несёт.**

Нужна ли тут запятая? Если да, то почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*В той, которую мы обсудили выше, был выдан дополнительный мут, который был верным, но оказался неверным (почему?) **вследствие обстоятельств**, за которые никто ответственность на данный момент не несёт.*

Оборот действительно не обособляется **при данной структуре** предложения, но сказуемое само по себе самодостаточно и без оборота. Можно поставить оборот в другую позицию, и тогда он будет обособляться: ...*но, вследствие некоторых обстоятельств, оказался неверным.*

Это **обстоятельство причины** с факультативным обособлением, что завит от ряда факторов. В приведенном примере обстоятельство стоит **в конце предложения**, где чаще не обособляется.

Интонационно это проявляется **в отсутствии паузы**, что и выглядит как тесная связь оборота со сказуемым.

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114

Comment: В вашем ответе есть огромное противоречие: вы написали, что, находясь перед сказуемым, причинный оборот обособляется, а потом сразу же написали, что обособление факультативно. Так обособление факультативное или обособление перед сказуемым?

Comment: Такой рейтинг, а пишете бессмыслицу. Нехорошо.

Comment: В комментариях можно уточнить ответ или предложить его улучшение. Спасибо за то, что вы соблюдаете правила. Пожалуйста, прочитайте внимательно весь текст. В общем случае (по Розенталю) это факультативное обособление, а в данном случае (в конце предложения) оборот не обособлен. Но  при изменении позиции он может обособляться.

Comment: Ничего не понял. То есть в конце не факультативно, а не в конце факультативно, а перед сказуемым тоже не факультативно и обязательно нужно обособлять.

Comment: Пожалуйста, прочитайте эту тему у Розенталя: Роль места, занимаемого обстоятельством этого типа, можно показать на таких примерах: Метелица, по совету пастушка, продолжал шагать по нескошенному лугу (Ф.); Больной оставался на диете по совету врача; И т.д.

Comment: Я прочитал, но ничего там не понял. То есть вы хотите сказать, что причинный оборот обособляется перед сказуемым, а не обособляется после сказуемого. Это вы хотите сказать этими примерами, которые привели.

Comment: Я хочу сказать,что нет тесной связи оборота и сказуемого, оборот может обособляться или не обособляться. У Розенталя: "обособление или необособление обстоятельства зависит от степени распространенности оборота, его близости к основной части предложения, наличия добавочных оттенков значения, места по отношению к сказуемому, стилистической задачи и т. д., поэтому обособление факультативно". Можно распространить оборот, и тогда он будет обособляться и в конце предложения.

Comment: Ага, то есть всё таки факультативно. Вы написали, что причинный оборот, который находится в позиции перед сказуемым обособляется. То есть эта часть вашего ответа неверная? Вы написали: ‟Можно поставить оборот в другую позицию, и тогда он будет обособляться”, а потом указали на эту позицию с помощью примера.

Comment: Извините, но я все сказала, и даже больше, чем нужно и чем хотела сказать. Здесь не разрешены распространенные комментарии.

Comment: А как вы, как эксперт, посоветуете мне поступать? Следует ли мне обособлять оборот с ‟вследствие”, если он стоит перед сказуемым? Нужно ли мне обособлять в таком предложении: ‟Вследствие этих событий мне придётся отказаться от похода”?

Comment: Просто если взять корпус классики в Нацкорпусе, то там 99 из 100 таких оборотов не обособляется в позиции перед сказуемым.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не нужна. См. на грамоте.ру.

> Оборот не обособляется, если он входит в состав сказуемого или тесно
> связан с ним по смыслу. ... *В комнате Коли вечер наступал **согласно
> законам природы**, поскольку свет там давно не горел.* Л.
> Петрушевская, Козел Ваня.

Comment: Верно, но чего ж пример с другим? Это смешно.

Comment: Вы правы, я не досмотрел. Надо было либо выбрать пример с "вследствие", либо не приводить  совсем.

Answer (score 1):

‟Вследствие” – это такой же причинный предлог, как и ‟из-за”. Запятой нет, потому что причинные обороты не обособляются.