# Обособление оборота "вследствие обстоятельств"

Tags: запятые, предлоги

Я решал [задание](https://rus-ege.sdamgia.ru/problem?id=38847) на Решу.ЕГЭ и увидел следующий фрагмент текста.

**Взрослому человеку(,) вследствие неизбежных обстоятельств(,) приходится основное время тратить на работу и гораздо меньше  — на учебу, познание мира.**

На сайте запятые стоят. Однако недавно я задавал [вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474037/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5) по поводу похожего предложения, которое было написано мной. Мне объяснили достаточно ясно, что запятая не нужна, хотя, мне кажется, ситуации аналогичны.

Объясните, пожалуйста, кто прав?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оборот обособляется:

*Взрослому человЕку, **вследствие неизбежных обстоЯтельств**, приходится основное время тратить на рабОту  / и гораздо меньше  — на учебу, познание мира.*

**[По правилу Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114)**  обособление обстоятельственных оборотов является **факультативным**, но в данном случае такое решение наиболее приемлемо.

Из факторов, способствующих обособлению, можно назвать **позицию** оборота между дополнением и сказуемым (в безличных предложениях они тесно связаны между собой), а также значительную **распространённость** оборота и самого предложения.

Поэтому оборот не включается в основное содержание предложения  и дается как **дополнительное** сообщение.

Окончательная проверка делается **по интонации**. При отсутствии обособления предложение трудно  прочитать в одну фонетическую фразу. Распространенное предложение приходится делить **на смысловые отрезки**, а в данном случае сделать это  затруднительно.